# Api Platform - Hydra - accessing hydra:member with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having problem that I cannot solve. I need to print out response objects with javascript and I don't know how to do that. I have response like.this:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Client",
  "@id": "/clients",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/clients/1",
      "@type": "Client",
      "uuid": "e3rer445",
      "number": " 0483",
      "name": "Tom Beringer",
      "adresses": [
      {
          "@id": "/client_addresses/1",
          "@type": "http://schema.org/Thing",
          "address": {
              "@id": "/addresses/1",
              "@type": "http://schema.org/Thing",
              "address": "Postbus 1d425"
          }
      },
  ]
},
```

And now I need to print out the result of all client details, so when I do this:

```
axios.get('/clients')
      .then(res => {
      this.users = res.data['hydra:member']
  })
```

I successfully print out the name, number, but when I try to print out addresses i get.this as a result:

```
<td><span>[
  {
    "@id": "/client_addresses/3",
    "@type": "http://schema.org/Thing",
        "address": {
        "@id": "/addresses/3",
        "@type": "http://schema.org/Thing",
        "address": "niet meer gebruiken"
     }
  } 
</span></td>
```

But what I need is just.this address: niet meer gebruiken
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/api-platform/api-doc-parser to parse the Hydra API documentation?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It is possible.

Try with this:

```
res.data['hydra:member'][0]['adresses'][0]['address']['address']
```

or

```
res.data['hydra:member'][0]['adresses'][0].address.address
```

That will work fine if you only have one address object nested. In case you have more objects inside you should iterate over the array of addresses.

This will be/contain your array of addresses:

```
 res.data['hydra:member'][0]['adresses']
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jonathan's answer, here's some explanation.

You don't have to create a default config, but make sure when making a request to the api generated by Api platform, to add an 'Accept' header. The default seems to be 'application/ld+json'.

Adding 'Accept': 'application/json' to your headers will make sure you only get your objects without all the extra tags Api platform adds.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a config default.

`./main.js`

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.get['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.delete['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried accessing the property like this?

```
res.data['hydra:member']['addresses][0]['address']['address']
```

If there is more than one address object nested within your addresses array, you might need to iterate over it.